# How to open new activity within a dialog arg

Tags: java, android, android-listview, dialog

How Can I open my SettingsActivty when I click on the "Advanced" section in my list view dialog? here is my code

```
public void show (){
        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.dialog_list, new String[]{"Themes", "Advanced", "Help"}));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // Do your stuff here.
            }
        });
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Settings");
        dialog.setContentView(listView);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

I know it will be something like this but how can I fit that into the specific argument

```
Intent iinent= new Intent(Homeactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
startActivity(iinent);
```

Comment: you want to open a new activity on dialog button click or listview item click?

Comment: @Fahim My dialog displays a listview. when I click on the second item which is Advanced I want it to open a new activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
             @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                switch(arg2){
                 case(1):
                  Intent iinent= new Intent(Homeactivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                  startActivity(iinent);

                  }                    
                }
```

To further clarify, arg0 is your adapter, arg1 is the view you clicked, arg2 is the position and arg3 is the id.

Edit: to clarify even further, since the Advanced is the second String and the list positions have a zero based index (they start at 0) it will be in the position number 1;

There are a number of other ways we can go at this:

Through the adapter (possibly your best choice).

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     String item = arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg1);
     if(item.equals("Advanced"){
       Intent intent = Intent(Homeactivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);                     
     }                                
 }
```

Through the view:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        TextView text = (TextView) arg1;
        if(text.getText().toString().equals("Advanced"){
           Intent intent = Intent(Homeactivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);             
         }                                
     }
```

Comment: This works thanks! So can I change the case to (2) for the item below it?

Comment: Yes you can, also i made a few edits to further clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to call activity on Advanced item set on position second:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                                    if(position==1){
                                        Intent iinent= new Intent(Homeactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
                                        startActivity(iinent);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```